# Find match in csv file

Tags: awk

I have two CSV files.

1.csv
contains:

```
46700468915;2000
```

2.csv
contains:

```
4670046;Tele2
```

I am trying to searching from 2.csv if 4670046 exists in 1.csv which is does and then take from 2.csv Tele2 and add in 1.csv if no match do not add

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} $2 in a {print $0, a[$2]}' OFS='\t' 2.csv 1.csv
```

Comment: I feel like this question would be better suited to StackOverflow. You can try here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=awk+csv. Also, I'm struggling to understand what you are asking, but it sounds like you want to take column data from `2.csv` and add it to `1.csv` if the first column matches?

Comment: Yes correct if match is found

Comment: Maybe this answer could be of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226479/conditional-append-of-strings-on-fields-in-a-csv-file

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here:

1. you need to set awk's field separator appropriately: by default it is whitespace, whereas your files appear to be delimited by semicolons
2. you are trying to match on a partial field: `4670046` is in `a` but `46700468915` isn't
3. you seem to be confused about which field you are matching, `$1` or `$2`

If you know that you want to match the first 7 characters, you can try

```
awk -F ';' '
  NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {k = substr($1,1,7)} k in a {print $0, a[k]}
' OFS='\t' 2.csv 1.csv
```

or equivalently

```
awk '
  BEGIN{FS=";"; OFS="\t"} 
  NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {k = substr($1,1,7)} k in a {print $0, a[k]}
' 2.csv 1.csv
```

Ex. given

```
$ head ?.csv
==> 1.csv <==
46700468915;2000

==> 2.csv <==
4670046;Tele2
```

then

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"; OFS="\t"} NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {k = substr($1,1,7)} k in a {print $0, a[k]}' 2.csv 1.csv
46700468915;2000    Tele2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` solution should be much faster but here is an example, how to achieve this via `bash` script, which `read` each line of `2.csv` as `-a`rray and then uses `sed` to do the changes (the `if` statement is not essential part of the script).

```bsh
$ cat ./script.sh
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_FILE="./1.csv"
ORIGIN_FILE="./2.csv"

# In order to append new column to a line, comment-out -i.bak
while IFS=';' read -r -a line
do
        if grep -q "${line[0]}" "$TARGET_FILE"
        then
                sed "/^${line[0]}/ s/$/;${line[1]}/" "$TARGET_FILE" #-i.bak
        fi
done < "$ORIGIN_FILE"

echo '-----'

# In order to replace the second column of a line, comment-out -i.bak
while IFS=';' read -r -a line
do
        if grep -q "${line[0]}" "$TARGET_FILE"
        then
                sed -r "s/(^${line[0]}.*\;).*$/\1${line[1]}/" "$TARGET_FILE" #-i.bak
        fi
done < "$ORIGIN_FILE"
```

Example of usage:

```bsh
$ cat 1.csv
46700468915;2000
46700568916;3000
46700668917;4000

$ cat 2.csv
4670046;Tele2
4670047;Tele3
4670048;Tele4

$ ./script.sh
46700468915;2000;Tele2
46700568916;3000
46700668917;4000
-----
46700468915;Tele2
46700568916;3000
46700668917;4000
```

Comment: I get the correct result however the output gets 46700468915;2000;Tele2
46700568916;3000
46700668917;4000

Comment: Hi, @Batistuta2020, you need to *enable* the `-i` option of `sed` in order do do the changes in the place of the file. Then the `sed` command will not output anything, but will change the file. Also you must remove the entire `while` loop that you don't want to use, otherwise it will continue to produce an output.